# How to only display first node in xsl:when

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl:when that displays:

- categories
- images

What I want is to show all the images but show the category name only once above them since they are all the same for that image set.

Q: How do I accomplish this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/commissions/entry">
    <xsl:variable name="category-path" select="commission-category"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="imageset/item">               
            <xsl:variable name="image-path" select="image/filename"/>

            <li>
                    <!-- this is the category name --> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="$name-path" />

                    <!-- this is the photo -->
                    <img src="{$image-path}" alt="" />
            </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$name-path" />
```

*before* the `<xsl:for-each>` instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/commissions/entry">
    <xsl:variable name="category-path" select="commission-category"/>

    <!-- this is the category name --> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$name-path" />

    <xsl:for-each select="imageset/item">               
            <xsl:variable name="image-path" select="image/filename"/>

            <li>

                    <!-- this is the photo -->
                    <img src="{$image-path}" alt="" />
            </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
```